# Reading data from url in List

Tags: dart

I know I can read data from URL as:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

new HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQvf9tp4-fETDJbC-HRmRKvVFAXEAGO4lrYPpVeiYkB6nqqXdSs3CjX0eBMvjIoEeX9_qU6K2RWmzVk/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'))
          .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
          .then((HttpClientResponse response) => response.transform(new Utf8Decoder()).listen(print));
```

Where the above print the response I'm getting.
Also, I know that the read string can be put into a file by replacing the last statement to be:

```dart
.then((HttpClientResponse response) => response.pipe(new File('foo.txt').openWrite()));
```

In the other hand, I know I can put a string into CSV as:

```dart
// dependencies: csv: ^4.0.3
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues = const CsvToListConverter().convert(yourString);
```

But how can I combine them together, so that I read the data from url using `http` as shown above, and decode the returned response into `csv` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have an easier time if you mark your method with `async` so you can use the `await` keyword instead of trying using the `.then()` method. So something like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  print(await csv());
}

Future<List<List<dynamic>>> csv() async {
  final request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQvf9tp4-fETDJbC-HRmRKvVFAXEAGO4lrYPpVeiYkB6nqqXdSs3CjX0eBMvjIoEeX9_qU6K2RWmzVk/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'));
  final response = await request.close();
  final csvString = await response.transform(const Utf8Decoder()).first;
  return const CsvToListConverter().convert(csvString);
}
```

You can read more about this here: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: How can I get the returned to the main file, I tried defining it as `Future<List<List<dynamic>>> csv() async {.. return rowsAsListOfValues;}`, but could not call it as `List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues = await csv();`

Comment: Updated my answer so we now have a `csv()` method. Note that this method must be specified to return a `Future` since it is marked as `async`.